# Format as Table without Losing Existing Cell Formatting (no merged cells being used) Excel 365

Tags: microsoft-excel

The other post about this did not answer the core question.
I do not have any merged cells in my spreadsheet.

How do I turn a group of cells into a table without losing the existing formatting I've already applied to the cells, and how to create a table with no formatting?

Comment: For those of us not in the loop can you provide a link to that other post? (to ensure we don't go over already covered ground)

Comment: Create a custom table style with no chosen format. then choose that for your table.

Answer (score 1):

**Insert** the **Table** directly and you can select the **None** table style in **Table Design**:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Ah! I didn't see the None option. Thanks so much!